# google marker open activity when marker is clicked

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I have created an app that shows the list of bar locations by a marker on a map taken from a database on firebase.

each bar has a list of beverages.

what I wish to happen is that when a marker is clicked a new activity will open with the name of the bar selected at the top of the new activity

What i wish to happen is that when the marker is clicked it will open a new activity

//Declaration list of venues

```
List<Venue> venueList;
```

//onCreate method

```
    venueList = new ArrayList<>();
    mVenues.push().setValue(marker);
```

//onMapsReady method, gets the venues into the map

```
  public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
    googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
    mVenues.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot s : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                Venue venue = s.getValue(Venue.class);

                venueList.add(venue);
                for (int i = 0; i < venueList.size(); i++)
                {
                    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(venue.venueLat,venue.venueLong);
                    if (mMap != null) {
                        marker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                                .position(latLng).title(venue.venueName));
                                           }
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }

    });
```

//Marker Click Event

```
  //CMarker click event to take user to purchase beverage
    mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener(){
        public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
            String title = marker.getTitle();
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < venueList.size();) {
                    //getting the selected venue
                    Venue venue = venueList.get(i);
                    //creating an intent

                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), viewbeverageActivity.class);

                    //putting venue name and id to intent
                    intent.putExtra(VENUE_ID, venue.getVenueId());
                    intent.putExtra(VENUE_NAME, venue.getVenueName());

                    //starting the activity with intent
                    startActivity(intent);

                }
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
```

//Venue Class

```
package uk.ac.ferry_j2ulster.beerapp;

import com.google.firebase.database.IgnoreExtraProperties;

public class Venue {
    private String venueId;
    public String venueName;
    private String venueType;
    public double venueLat;
    public double venueLong;


    public Venue(){

    }

    public Venue(String venueId, String venueName, String venueType,double venueLat, double venueLong) {
        this.venueId = venueId;
        this.venueName = venueName;
        this.venueType = venueType;
        this.venueLat =  venueLat;
        this.venueLong =  venueLong;


    }

    public String getVenueId() {
        return venueId;
    }

    public String getVenueName() {
        return venueName;
    }

    public String getVenueType() {
        return venueType;
    }

    public double getVenueLong() { return venueLong;
    }

    public double getVenueLat() {return venueLat;
    }
}
```

I hope to open a new activity with the bar that was selected as a title at the top

no errors, not sure how to start with this one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are using a loop to go through each Venue, and calling `startActivity()` for all venues.

Instead, define a HashMap that will map each Marker ID to a Venue ID:

```
 Map<String, String> mMarkerMap = new HashMap<>();
```

Then, put an entry in the HashMap for each Marker:

```
@Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    for (DataSnapshot s : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
        Venue venue = s.getValue(Venue.class);

        venueList.add(venue);
        for (int i = 0; i < venueList.size(); i++)
        {
            LatLng latLng = new LatLng(venue.venueLat,venue.venueLong);
            if (mMap != null) {
                marker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                        .position(latLng).title(venue.venueName));
                //Added:
                mMarkerMap.put(marker.getId(), venue.getVenueId());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then, when the user taps a Marker, get the title and Venue ID from the Marker/HashMap, and send it to the new activity:

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

    //...........

    mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
            String venueID = mMarkerMap.get(marker.getId());
            String venueName = marker.getTitle();
            Intent intent = new Intent(MapActivity.this, NewActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra(VENUE_NAME, venueName);
            intent.putExtra(VENUE_ID, venueID);
            startActivity(intent);

            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

In the new activity, simply get the title and Venue ID Strings passed in:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_new);

    String venueName = getIntent().getStringExtra(MapActivity.VENUE_NAME);
    if (title != null) {
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);
    }

    String venueID = getIntent().getStringExtra(MapActivity.VENUE_ID);
    if (venueID != null) {
        //use venue ID to get the information about this venue
    }

    //.......
 }
```

Comment: sorry i am trying to get the ID and the title so i can then display the beverages that are linked to that bar. The below code opens each bar on the list but needs to be the bar on the marker

Comment: I edited it there with the venue class and my updated onMap method with the markerCLICK. I get all bars on the list opened using this

Comment: Daniel can thank you enough, that worked perfect, your a gent :-)

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass venue information also to the activity :

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
mMap = googleMap;

//...........

mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
        String title = marker.getTitle();
        Venue venue = NULL;
        for(int i=0;i<venueList.size();i++)
        {
          if(venueList.get(i).getTitle().equal(title))
             venue = venueList.get(i);
        }
        Intent intent = new Intent(MapActivity.this, NewActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("title", title);
        intent.putExtra("venue",venue.toJSON());
        startActivity(intent);

        return false;
    }
});
```

}

Make a **toJSON()** function in your venue class and also **fromJSON()** which will help you in sending venue data as well.